# Count specific numbers in list

Tags: list, count, scheme, racket

How do I use `count` for counting specific numbers in list?

```
(define lst '(1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4)
(count 2 lst);; what should I use at the place of '2'
```

But it is resulting the following error.

> count: contract violation
>     expected: procedure?
>     given: 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count` counts the number of elements of the list for which the procedure returns `true`. In this case you want a procedure that only returns true if the element is 2: `(lambda (x) (equal? x 2))`.

In full, you can do

```
(define lst '(1 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 4 4))
(count (lambda (x) (equal? x 2)) lst)
```

Side note: you can shorten it by replacing the lambda expression with `(curry equal? 2)`.

Comment: I have never seen the use of `curry` before. Is it mainly for replacing lambda expression? @Gibstick

Comment: @Toat Yes, that's how I use it (sparingly).